# Postgres Recursive Query, CTE goes in infinite loop inside postgres function using sql?

Tags: postgresql, function, recursion, common-table-expression

Trying to make a postgres function, inside of which I made a CTE, to recursively iterate through hierarchical data (Parent child relationship)
**MY Table structure**
[image]

In this I need to recursively iterate if text_id != new_text_id and stop (terminating condition) when **text_id == new_text_id**

Table Schema for reference

```
create table demoTextTable
(
    text_id serial primary key,
    text_details character varying,
    new_text_id integer
)

insert into demoTextTable(text_details, new_text_id)
values ('Comment 1', 2),
       ('Comment 1 updated 1st Time',3),
       ('Comment 1 updated 2nd Time',4),
       ('Comment 1 updated 3rd Time',5),
       ('Comment 1 updated 4th Time',5);
```

My Postgres Function

```
create or replace function get_text_history(textId integer)
RETURNS Table (
    text_id integer,
    text_details varchar,
    new_text_id integer)
AS $$
BEGIN
WITH RECURSIVE textHierarchy AS (

    select tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id
    from text_master tm where tm.text_id = textId

    UNION ALL

    select tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id
    FROM textHierarchy AS txtHr, text_master AS tm where tm.text_id != txtHr.new_text_id
    and txtHr.new_text_id is not null
)
select * from textHierarchy;
END;
$$ Language plpgsql;
```

OK So tried more and got the inside CTE working but if I execute it inside function then it gives error on executing function as

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_text_history(integer) line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

**My Updated Function**:-

```
create or replace function get_text_history(textId integer)
RETURNS Table (
    text_id integer,
    text_details varchar,
    new_text_id integer)
AS $$
BEGIN
WITH RECURSIVE textHierarchy AS (

    select dtbl.text_id, dtbl.text_details, dtbl.new_text_id
    from demoTextTable dtbl where dtbl.text_id = textId

    UNION

    select dtbl.text_id, dtbl.text_details, dtbl.new_text_id
    FROM demoTextTable dtbl where dtbl.text_id != dtbl.new_text_id or 
    dtbl.text_id = dtbl.new_text_id order by text_id asc

)
select * from textHierarchy;
END;
$$ Language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` to avoid duplicates. Also, your `SELECT` is lacking an `INTO` clause.

Comment: Tried it getting error as record "curr_rec" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate. Can you please try it out at your end.

Comment: create or replace function get_text_history(textId integer)
RETURNS Table (
    text_id integer,
    text_details varchar,
    new_text_id integer)
AS $$
DECLARE
    curr_rec record;
BEGIN
WITH RECURSIVE textHierarchy AS (
 
 select tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id into curr_rec
 from text_master tm where tm.text_id = textId
 
 UNION
 
 select tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id
 FROM textHierarchy AS txtHr,text_master AS tm where txtHr.text_id != curr_rec.new_text_id
 and txtHr.new_text_id is not null
)
select * from textHierarchy;
END; ..

Comment: No, I cannot try it out, because I don't have the table definitions. Please [edit] the question and add all relevant information there. Actually, you should use `LANGUAGE sql` rather than `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

Comment: OK Adding required info

Comment: Can you please try now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use SQL, not PL/pgSQL, you need `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`, and you need to join with `=` rather than `<>`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_text_history(textId integer)
RETURNS TABLE (
    text_id integer,
    text_details varchar,
    new_text_id integer
) LANGUAGE sql AS
$$WITH RECURSIVE textHierarchy AS (
    SELECT tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id
    FROM demotexttable tm 
    WHERE tm.text_id = textId
  UNION
    SELECT tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id
    FROM textHierarchy AS txtHr 
        JOIN demotexttable AS tm ON tm.text_id = txtHr.new_text_id
    WHERE txtHr.new_text_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM textHierarchy$$;
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz solution worked like a charm :) But have a doubt why does this function you posted doesn't work with pl/pgSql ?. Why can't  table data  be returned using pl/pgSql or why does it throws error as 'ERROR:  query has no destination for result data'

Comment: Because your query has no destination for the result data. Like I wrote in my comment to your question, you need an `INTO` clause for a `SELECT` statement in PL/pgSQL, or (what would be the correct thing here) you would need to use `RETURN QUERY`. But why use all the unnecessary complications of PL/pgSQL syntax if a simple SQL function can do?

Comment: Yes understood but tried it without using INTO and it worked here  in next comment

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_text_history(textId integer)
RETURNS TABLE (
    text_id integer,
    text_details varchar,
    new_text_id integer
) AS $$
BEGIN
return QUERY
WITH RECURSIVE textHierarchy AS (
    SELECT tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id
    FROM demotexttable tm 
    WHERE tm.text_id = textId
  UNION
    SELECT tm.text_id, tm.text_details, tm.new_text_id
    FROM textHierarchy AS txtHr 
        JOIN demotexttable AS tm ON tm.text_id = txtHr.new_text_id
    WHERE txtHr.new_text_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM textHierarchy;
END;
$$ Language plpgsql;

Comment: Yes, just like I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Does postgres provide  OPTION (MAXRECURSION Number) ?. Can't seem to find it and tried it, it gives error

Comment: No, but you can drag along a 'level' column that you initialize with 1 and increase with every iteration.

Comment: OK Thanks. @Laurenz Albe